# How to get ephemeralPublicKey instead of wrappedKey and EC_v1 instead of RSA_v1 in Apple Pay PKPayment object data

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, applepay

[image]How to get ephemeralPublicKey instead of wrappedKey and version EC_v1 instead of RSA_v1

```
["header": {
              publicKeyHash = "wjjJ53GAdAQ2l=";
              transactionId = 9ceae2a745f4b071e47553fa45;
              wrappedKey = "oEGOwx6fIy+Lmu8k6XgT3WExyDwFg1dOqis9y4B+99BGmrMx1W0M9athPvv9DQoKn0H9g==";
            },   "data": zFATMVYnHDeLrN8nQXPeBjQFxAn8lADEAX+DB3it6Fokh4J9L2QftQ2S408sA==,   "version": RSA_v1,   "signature": MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEACgYIKA ]
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue while integrating apple pay in Payfort Payment SDK, they support ECC format and I was getting RSA format from apple, Still finding the solution

Comment: @ParthPandya How to create ECC format Certificate in Apple Developer Account ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your certificate is based on the RSA and not on the ECC.

Information from Apple :

ephemeralPublicKey : X.509 encoded key bytes. Base64 encoded as a string, Ephemeral public key bytes. RSA_v1 only.

wrappedKey : A Base64 encoded string. The symmetric key wrapped using your RSA public key. EC_v1 only.

Source : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014929-CH8-SW3

Comment: When I generate CSR, Selected key pair information is Algorithm : ECC and Key Size:256 bits but still I am getting same result.

Comment: You will receive the ephemeralKey when you create a new transaction in the ApplePay workflow

Comment: Hi All, Did anyone find the answer, I also facing the same issue. I tried with ECC - 256 still finding the wrappedKey.